# Concatenation and count SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I have this dataset :

| Product | Account |
| --- | --- |
| Product X | Account 1 |
| Product X | Account 1 |
| Product Y | Account 1 |
| Product Y | Account 1 |
| Product Y | Account 1 |

And in my Table matrix i want this output

|  | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Account 1 | Product X*2; Product Y*3 |

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this directly in SSRS.

You have a couple of options. I would suggest you do this in your dataset query but if your tags are correct then it looks like the dataset is not create from a SQL query.

Alternatively you could use a matrix and have a row group by account and a column group by product. Then set the data value to `COUNT` rather then the default `SUM`. It won't be in a flat list like you want but might suffice.